# How do I add a screen edge pan gesture recognizer to handle this pop animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I subclassed `UINavigationController` and created a noninteractive animation object that handles the push and pop transitions. To complete this, how do I add a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to handle the custom pop animation below? I'm sort of confused on where to go from here so any help would be great, thanks!

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate = self
        isNavigationBarHidden = true

    }

}

extension CustomNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // noninteractive animator objects
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        switch operation {

        case .push:
            return CustomPushAnimator()

        case .pop:
            return CustomPopAnimator()

        default:
            return nil

        }

    }

    // the interactive animator controller
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, interactionControllerFor animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {

        switch animationController {

        case is CustomPopAnimator:
            return CustomInteractiveController()

        default:
            return nil

    }

}

// the noninteractive push animator
class CustomPushAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    // push transition duration
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {

        return 0.2

    }

    // push transition animation
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let viewWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let viewHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)

        containerView.addSubview((toViewController?.view)!)
        toViewController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: viewWidth, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            toViewController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
        }, completion: { finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })

    }

}

// the noninteractive pop animator
class CustomPopAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    // pop transition duration
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {

        return 0.2

    }

    // pop transition animation
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let viewWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let viewHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)

        containerView.insertSubview((toViewController?.view)!, belowSubview: (fromViewController?.view)!)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            fromViewController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: viewWidth, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
        }, completion: { finished in
            fromViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })

    }

}

class CustomInteractiveController: NSObject, UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning {

    func startInteractiveTransition(_ transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        // I think the edge screen pan gesture goes here? Again, any advice is greatly appreciated!

    }

}
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted this question, I'd appreciate a reason. I put a lot of time into researching and writing this code and I asked a very specific question, what gives?

Comment: Did you found an answer how to link them together? I can't find also ah

Answer (score 1):

In general, the procedure for writing an interactive custom transition animation is:

1. Before the transition begins, you must have given the view controller in charge of the transition a delegate.
2. You'll have a gesture recognizer that tracks the interactive gesture. When the gesture recognizer recognizes, it triggers the transition to the new view controller.
3. As the transition begins, the delegate will be asked for an animation controller. You will return a UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning object.
4. The delegate will also be asked for an interaction controller. You will return a UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning object (or `nil` to prevent the transition from being interactive). This object implements `startInteractiveTransition(_:)`.
5. The gesture recognizer continues by constantly calling `updateInteractiveTransition(_:)` on the transition context, as well managing the frames of the animation.
6. Sooner or later the gesture will end. At this point, we must decide whether to declare the transition completed or cancelled. A typical approach is to say that if the user performed more than half the full gesture, that constitutes completion; otherwise, it constitutes cancellation. We finish the animation accordingly.
7. The animation is now completed, and its completion function is called. We must call the transition context's `finishInteractiveTransition` or `cancelInteractiveTransition`, and then call its `completeTransition(_:)` with an argument stating whether the transition was finished or cancelled.
8. Our `animationEnded` is called, and we clean up.

In the past, you could use a UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition object to help you, but I always use a UIViewPropertyAnimator for my custom transition animations nowadays (iOS 10 and later); you would have to start by rewriting your entire code to do that. I usually keep three instance properties: the UIViewPropertyAnimator, the transition context (because the gesture recognizer needs a reference), and a Bool flag saying whether this is an interactive animation (because the same code can be reused for interactive and noninteractive versions of the same animation).

Comment: I took your advice and refactored the animation using `UIViewPropertyAnimator`. I created a Gist https://gist.github.com/sconewolf/7a849fc691b63cf8721d6151831feae8 with the edits but cannot figure out how to link the pan gesture recognizer & handler to the interactive controller (at the bottom). What is the missing link? There are a ton of tutorials for this using `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` (which I have done in the past but loathe because of the 0.999 hack) but have found no tutorials using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` (obviously because it didn't exist until now with iOS 10).